# RadAjaxManager in a user control with at most one such manager per page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

It is a well known error if you try to add the `RadAjaxManager` to your page twice:

> Only one instance of a RadAjaxManager can be added to the page

[Telerik explains](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-user-controls.html) how you can solve this for design-time issues with a proxy control.

For most of the controls we use on pages, this error does not fire, even though each of these controls have a `RadAjaxManager` on them, sometimes even inside a repeater (accidentally, but still, the error doesn't throw). However, with one such control (a dynamic button) we have added it to several places on the page with no problem, possibly because this was all the same control, but nested in another control we receive the error above again, as soon as we add it to the page.

I have tried to solve it by:

- [adding the control dynamically](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/adding-a-radajaxmanager-in-a-webpart/) to the page, but because control events fire before the page events, this leads to some dynamic behavior to not occur anymore.
- adding the `RadAjaxManager` dynamically only once to the control, with built-in extra checks, like so:

  ```
  private RadAjaxManager GetAjaxManager()
  {
      var ctl = this.FindControl("ajaxManager");
      if (ctl != null)
      {
          return (RadAjaxManager)ctl;
      }

      // alternative method
      var mgr = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
      if (mgr != null)
      {
          return mgr;
      }

      // control is never found, always returns null
      return null;
  }

  protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
  {
      if (this.GetAjaxManager() == null)
      {
          // ajax mgr is never found, and this always throws
          // "cannot add multiple times" error
          var ajaxManager = new RadAjaxManager();
          ajaxManager.ID = "ajaxManager";
          this.Controls.Add(ajaxManager);
      }
  }
  ```

  - Several variants of the above

The result is either: the control is never found and is therefore added more than once, resulting in the above error, or the control is added but too late in the process for the other controls in the usercontrol, resulting in several AJAX events not happening.

How should I add the `RadAjaxManager` to a user-control that is itself used inside several other user-controls, such that the manager only occurs once on the page and/or such that `RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent` actually works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plane A - add the RadAjaxManager to the page level, not to the user controls. Thus, the user controls can have RadAjaxManagerProxy controls, the static GetCurrent() method will work.

Plan B - use RadAjaxPanel controls if you want self-contained user controls. They have an ajaxRequest() client-side method and a server side event for that, and since user controls are usually smallish, you will likely be able to get away with a single panel for them.

Plan C - leave AJAX setup to the parent page. If a parent user control is already AJAX-enabled, its entire content will travel with the postback, so neesting more AJAX settings on inner user controls may not bring you a performance benefit.

Plan D - use only asp:UpdatePanel controls with UpdateMode=Conditional so you will have extremely fine-grained control of your partial rendering.

Comment: Thanks, you made some good points. Looks like we should get rid of the per-control usage of RadAjaxManager. We used your plan D in several occasions already, I think we should expand on it in combination with placing RadAjaxManager on page level. We tried to force that from the control (as in: if it is not there, add it), but couldn't get this to work in practice. Pages in our case are skin templates, adding it always was not our original goal.

Comment: Glad my brainstorming helped a bit. I figured things are not very simple. As to the original issue - my best guess is thread safety. Perhaps a lock and a double null check singleton style would help?